# IE 11 ajax error - "SCRIPT65535: Argument not optional"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

The code below works in every browser except IE, following an error message `"SCRIPT65535: Argument not optional"`.

```
function _getChart(){

    $('.series-data').remove();

    var itm = window.item;
    var tp = window.type;
    var ord = window.order;
    var xd = window.xdata;
    var yd = window.ydata;

    var dt = {superAwesomeTypeNotIEvar : tp,
              superAwesomeItemNotIEvar : itm,
              superAwesomeOrderNotIEvar : ord,
              superAwesomeXdataNotIEvar : xd,
              superAwesomeYdataNotIEvar : yd,
              superAwesomeCharHeightNotIEvar : $('.charts-wrapper').height()};

    $.ajax({

        url: "ajax/data.php",
        cache: false,
        data: dt,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
           // Some fcs
```

As you can see I already tried renaming all the parameters to something that IE is not likely using for itself (e.g. the removeFilter story).

This is what the function looked like originally

```
function _getChart(){ 

    $('.series-data').remove();

    $.getJSON('ajax/data.php', {
        type : window.type,
        item : window.item,
        order: window.order,
        xdata : window.kurtosis,
        ydata : window.range,
        chartHeight : $('.charts-wrapper').height()}, function(data) {
```

If I set the `dt` array to just `{}` it all works, otherwise the error message above is shown.

> SCRIPT65535: Argument not optionalFile: jquery.js, Line: 4, Column: 13144

jQuery non-min file line where the error appears

```
jQuery.param = function( a, traditional ) {
    var prefix,
    s = [],
    add = function( key, value ) {
        // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
        value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );
        s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
    };
```

Why?

Comment: How is this function called? Is it a document load or element click?

Comment: Have you tried it without the dataType : "json" line?  Are you expecting the resulting data to be in JSON format?

Comment: Hey, its both load and element click and both fail. Yes, originally the function was $.getJSON and yes I am expecting json_encode() result.

Comment: Please don't develop using a minified jQuery. Use the full version so that line numbers in error messages have meaning.

Comment: Notice how the error is in *jquery.js*. This means you passed something to jQuery that, under the hood, is blowing up.

Comment: What are `window.item`, `window.order`, etc.?  My guess is that one of those is not what you think it is, like a DOM element or a function or something.

Comment: `dt` is not an array, it's an object

Comment: Gotta try to change the jQuery file to a nonmin one and see. Thx!

Comment: `jQuery.param = function( a, traditional ) {
 var prefix,
  s = [],
  add = function( key, value ) {
   // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
   value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value ); // CODE BREAKS HERE!
   s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
  };`

Comment: @Foxhoundn: That means it's a problem converting `dt` to a query string.  What does `dt` contain, exactly?  What does `console.dir(dt);` show you?  What are `window.item`, `window.order`, etc.?

Comment: Strings only, words.... // Set default chart data
 window.type = 'bar';
 window.item = 'knitwear';
 window.order = 'MktPotScoreOverall';
 window.kurtosis = 'KurtosisOverall';
 window.range = 'MktPotScoreAge0to24';
 window.orderType = 'DESC';

Comment: @Foxhoundn: Are you sure?  What about `xdata` and `ydata`? The comment, `// If value is a function, invoke it and return its value` might be what's going on here.

Comment: Yes I am sure, don't you think if I was passing a function or an object, it would not work in Chrome / Firefox?

Comment: You're using global variables, so don't be surprised when some data of yours gets clobbered.

Comment: @Foxhoundn: I guess that's true, though why does `removeFilter` only cause errors in IE ;-)

Comment: I see no indication that you've taken @RocketHazmat's advice and actually inspected the data. Have you? Or are you just assuming you're getting the values you assigned?

Comment: @RocketHazmat was right. Since you weren't too forthcoming with logging info, I fired up IE11 and checked the globals. There's a `window.item` function that is read-only. When you invoke it without args, you get the error you describe.

Comment: Changing the global (window.) variables to normal ones fixed the issue. Thanks everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, in my case it was an improperly formed value for 'data'.  Try checking dt in a debugger and making sure that it is the right data-type.

Comment: The problem was window.item being a reserved IE variable :)

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in ajax

```
  , cache: false
  , processData: false  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  , contentType: false  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
```

And try it again.

---

```
$.ajax({

    url: "ajax/data.php",
    cache: false,
    data: dt,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    success: function(data) {
```

### // Some fcs

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this will help, and I know you've already tried $.getJSON, but perhaps this would make IE 11 happier:

```
$.post('ajax/data.php', dt, function(data) {
    // do something with data
},'json');
```

Alternately, you could try using $.get instead.  That is missing the "cache:false" parameter, but I don't believe that's a bad thing.  Using it doesn't actually mean all browsers will comply.

Comment: Why would switching from GET to POST be the answer here?

Comment: It wouldn't, except perhaps the server code is expecting one or the other.

Comment: @jiy The server code is irrelevant here. The error is happening before the server is reached.

Comment: It's relevant because if the server code is expecting a "GET", and you send "POST" it won't work.  Unless of course you're using an agnostic solution.

Comment: Also, POST might actually work better than GET, especially depending on the JSON payload.

Comment: @jiy: What does "POST might actually work better than GET" mean?  How would that have any effect on the data sent from the server?

Comment: "Use POST when dealing with long requests – if you’re sending large amounts of data, or sensitive data over HTTPS, you will want to use POST. Some browser such as Internet Explorer place a limit on the URL string so this may break the action of some forms if you use GET." - http://www.sitepoint.com/key-differences-post/